# unable to submit properly Dynamic created forms using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi I am creating dynamic forms using jquery like this

```
      function testagenda(id){
         $("#AppendAgendaForm").append(' <form   method="POST" id=+'id'+" 
            enctype="multipart/form-data" >\n' +
             '{% csrf_token %}\n' +
             '<!--date field-->\n' +'<div class="row mb-3 mt-3">\n' +
             '<div class="col-md-1"></div>\n' +
             '<div class="col-md-2">\n' +
             '<h5 style="margin-top:32px;">Date</h5>\n' +
             '</div>\n' +
             '<div class="col-md-3">\n' +
             '<label>From</label>\n' +
             '<input autocomplete="off"  name="startDate"  type="text" id="dt1" class="form-control" placeholder="from" required>\n' +
             '{#<!--                                                    <input type="date" class="form-control"   value="{{ finalizedDate.startDate|date:\'Y-m-d\' }}"   id="fromvalidity" name="fromvalidity" required/>-->#}\n' +
             '</div>\n' +
             '<div class="col-md-3">\n' +
             ' <label>To</label>\n' +
             '<input autocomplete="off"  name="endDate"      type="text" id="dt2" class="form-control" placeholder="To" required>\n' +
             '{#<!--<input type="date" class="form-control"   value="{{ finalizedDate.endData|date:\'Y-m-d\' }}"  id="tovalidity" name="tovalidity" required/>-->#}\n' +
             '</div>\n' +
             '<div class="col-md-3"></div>\n' +
             '</div>\n' +
             '</form>\n' +
             '\n');
        }
```

**as I have diff Id for every form .** And Use can create even more then 100 forms . Now How I Can submit every form Independently using max 1 function etc ?

Comment: Code alignment? can you edit

Comment: (max 1 function etc..) that's not clear :) ?Where are you appending the submit button?

Comment: @Bilel  max 1 function means I want to just one function to  submit n Forms

Comment: I suggest you serialize all those inputs data in a structured json... anyway, if the unique ID is irrelevant to the server-side code, you can just use $("form").each(function () {...

Comment: @Bilel  I can't run each as I each form will operate as independently

Comment: I don't get it ! :) You expect a unique button click to be handled by a function that would magically know which form is being used? You didn't answer my first comment yet... where I meant that you could append a submit button to each form. Then use click event on those buttons so we could submit their parent form...

Answer (score 0):

best way in case was  getting ID first using  `document.getElementbyID`  on Click . then `form(FormID).submit()`